# Google fluentd - using env variables in labels

Tags: logging, environment-variables, fluentd, stackdriver

I am trying to add labels in the config file of google-fluentd. As per the documentation https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#label-setup it states `labels` are used for static labels. But, is there any way that I can add environment variables as value to these labels?

```
...
<match **>
  @type google_cloud
  # Adding labels to the log metadata
  labels {
    "source": "transform",
    "transformId": "\"#{ENV['TRANSFORM_ID']}\""
  }
  buffer_type file
  buffer_path /var/log/google-fluentd/buffers
...
```

Here in above code snippet refers to main `/etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf` file. The static label `source: transform` gets added to the logs but, the `transformId` which gets the value from `env variable` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using:
`labels "#{ENV['LABEL_JSON']}"`

And then passing the env variable - key value pairs like
`"LABEL_JSON": "{\"TRANSFORM_ID\": \"transformId\", \"TRANSFORM_NAME\": \"jane\"}"`